# How to remember session after logging in via node.js Express Passport

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

Using the Passport module in node.js Express, I have successfully obtained a redirection after the visitor logs in through Facebook. The following is part of my code:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: '999999999999999',
  clientSecret: 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff',
  callbackURL: 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com/auth/facebook/callback'
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    done(null, profile);
  });
}));
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
  successRedirect: '/register?provider=facebook',
  failureRedirect: '/',
  failureFlash: true
}));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {done(null, user);});
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {done(null, obj);});
```

My question is: how do we remember the session? There does not seem to be a way to pass values out of the .nextTick() function, neither could I register a cookie...

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I have to initialize cookieParser() and cookieSession() before initializing the passport.

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cookieSession({
  secret: config.sessionSecret,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: config.sessionMaxAge
  }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
......
```

After that, we can access the information in req.user in the successRedirect callback.